# Weblogic/JDeveloper credential mapper issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I am migrating an ADF/BC4J application from 10g to 12c and it deploys OK if there are no EJBs in the application (we only need EJBs for a small webservice and possibly a timer service). However if I create a webservice, Timer EJB or even just an enmpy EJB and try to deploy it using JDeveloper to the built-in WLS server it fails because either "No credential mapper entry found..." or because "Data Source XXXXXX" already exists.

The only advice Google has on this problem seems to be to go to Application->Properties->Deployment and turn off "Auto Generate and Synchronize ..." but doing that means the Credential Mapper is not found, turning it on means the Application won't deploy because weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: Data Source OracleTRIPOSSecurity already exists.

Catch 22 - I have been bashing my head against this on-and-off for the last month but the project is coming to a point where we are going to have to cross this bridge - does anyone have any ideas? I'm sure it's some combination of settings/deployment options but I can't seem to find the right combination from the billions available.

Answer (score 0):

As is typical of these things not long after posting on here and elsewhere I arrived at a solution, possibly not the best but seems to work. The application had 3 JDBC connections defined, one was not used, one was used for the security realm and one for the application data. The one for the security realm seemed to be causing the problem so I removed it from the weblogic-applicaiton.xml and manually created it in the WLS console.

This seems to avoid the problem, at least for now but I would still be interested in why this problem only occurred when a minimal EJB was added to the project and also if there is a better way because having to add the JDBC connection manually is another thing to go wrong in the deployment process.